# Why use asprintf() instead of sprintf()?

Tags: c, printf, gnu, asprintf

I'm having a hard time understanding why you would need asprintf. 
Here in the manual it says

> The functions `asprintf()` and `vasprintf()` are analogs of `sprintf(3)` and
>   `vsprintf(3)`, except that they allocate a string large enough to hold
>   the output including the terminating null byte, and return a pointer
>   to it via the first argument.  This pointer should be passed to
>   `free(3)` to release the allocated storage when it is no longer needed.

So here is the example that I'm trying to understand:

```
asprintf(&buffer, "/bin/echo %s is cool", getenv("USER"));
```

What's the difference if the buffer allocates a string large enough vs saying char* = (string)

Comment: `asprintf()` and `vasprintf()` are GNU extensions. Added the GNU tag.

Comment: Hmm, I wonder if the asker is doing the exercises here:  http://exploit-exercises.com/nebula/level02?

Comment: A very good blog post about this topic can be found here: [memory-management-in-c-and-auto](http://insanecoding.blogspot.de/2014/06/memory-management-in-c-and-auto.html) ... btw. the complete blog is worthwhile reading

Comment: @jordanpg [OpenBSD](https://man.openbsd.org/printf.3) has it too. [NetBSD](https://man.netbsd.org/asprintf.3) too. The [FreeBSD](https://man.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=asprintf&sektion=3#HISTORY) man page has some details about its history: "The functions asprintf() and vasprintf() first appeared in the GNU C library. These were implemented by Peter Wemm in FreeBSD 2.2, but were later replaced with a different implementation from OpenBSD 2.3 by Todd C. Miller."

Comment: It is hard to understand why you don't see the difference - with `sprintf` you have to calculate string length, allocate memory, then do `sprintf` in buffer. `asprintf` directly returns a pointer.

Answer (score 149, accepted):

If you use `sprintf()` or `vsprintf()`, you need to allocate a buffer first, and you need to be sure that the buffer is large enough to contain what sprintf writes. Otherwise `sprintf()` will happily overwrite whatever memory lies beyond the end of the buffer.

```
char* x = malloc(5 * sizeof(char));
// writes "123456" +null but overruns the buffer
sprintf(x,"%s%s%s", "12", "34", "56");
```

... writes the '6' and the terminating `null` beyond the end of the space allocated to `x`, either corrupting some other variable, or causing a segmentation fault.

If you're lucky, it will trample on memory in-between allocated blocks, and will do no harm -- this time. This leads to intermittent bugs -- the hardest kind to diagnose. It's good to use a tool like *ElectricFence* that causes overruns to fail-fast.

A non-malicious user who provides an overlong input, could cause the program to behave in unexpected ways. A malicious user could exploit this as a way to get their own executable code into the system.

One guard against this is to use `snprintf()`, which truncates the string to the maximum length you supply.

```
char *x = malloc(5 * sizeof(char));
int size = snprintf(x, 5, "%s%s%s", "12", "34", "56"); // writes "1234" + null
```

The return value `size` is the length that *would have been* written if space was available -- *not including the terminating null*.

In this case, if `size` is greater than or equal to 5 then you know that truncation occurred - and if you didn't want truncation, you could allocate a new string and try `snprintf()` again.

```
char *x = malloc(BUF_LEN * sizeof(char));
int size = snprintf(x, 5, "%s%s%s", "12", "34", "56");
if (size >= BUF_LEN) {
    realloc(&x,(size + 1) * sizeof(char));
    snprintf(x, size + 1 , "%s%s%s", "12", "34", "56");
}
```

(That's a pretty naive algorithm, but it illustrates the point. There may yet be bugs in it, which further illustrates the point -- this stuff is easy to screw up.)

`asprintf()` does this in one step for you - calculates the length of the string, allocates that amount of memory, and writes the string into it.

```
char *x;
int size = asprintf(&x, "%s%s%s", "12", "34", "56");
```

In all cases, once you've finished with `x` you need to release it, or you leak memory:

```
free(x);
```

`asprintf()` is an implicit `malloc()`, so you have to check it worked, just as you would with `malloc()` or any other system call.

```
if (size == -1 ) {
   /* deal with error in some way */
}
```

Note that `asprintf()` is part of the GNU and BSD extensions to libc - you can't be sure it will be available in every C environment. `sprintf()` and `snprintf()` are part of the POSIX and C99 standards.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. Cleared up a lot of things

Comment: Also, [you should not cast the result of `malloc` (and family) in C](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Comment: Wait, if `size` is the characters written without the terminating null, shouldn't you realloc `(size+1) * sizeof(char)`?

Comment: @JoachimSauer thanks. Ah, C :) -- at least it demonstrates why `asprintf` is useful. The old way is really easy to screw up.

Comment: It is worth noting that asprintf is not part of the C or POSIX standards, and is a GCC and BSD extension. Although useful - which is what the question asked - it should be used fully aware that your C code's portability goes way down. http://linux.die.net/man/3/asprintf

Comment: Relented, 5 years later, and removed the casts on `malloc()`

Comment: I think I found a few problems in the `snprintf` snippet: 1. You want to pass BUF_LEN to the first snprintf(), not 5! 2. You need to do `x = realloc(x, (size + 1))`! realloc accepts a pointer, not a pointer to a pointer! 3. The second snprintf call should be (size+1), not 5!

Answer (score 22):

The benefit is security.

Numerous programs have allowed system exploits to occur by having programmer-supplied buffers overflowed when filled with user supplied data.

Having `asprintf` allocate the buffer for you guarantees that can't happen.

However you *must* check the return value of `asprintf` to ensure that the memory allocation actually succeeded.  See http://blogs.23.nu/ilja/2006/10/antville-12995/

Comment: I remember reading on this vaguely. Is this the only reason to use asprintf?

Comment: @BrandonLing well, in many cases it would make your code shorter, too!

Comment: @BrandonLing: It removes code duplication -- many times when you want a never-truncating `sprintf` you're forced to write your own function that does this anyway, so now you have it all wrapped up in a single, ready-made function, at the cost of portability.