# C String Return Function Returns Garbage

Tags: c, string, function, return

I'm having trouble return a string from a function. It prints out a garbage value in the main method. I saw a similar question on this forum but the results on that page didn't help me. I DO NOT want to pass another variable into the function. I want to be able to return the string value as is. How can I go about doing so?

```
char *LookupPath(char **argv, char **dir)
{
    /* String Name To Be Returned */
    char path_name[MAX_PATH_LEN] = {0};
    char *result = malloc(sizeof(path_name));
    int i;

    /* Check To See If File Name Is Already An Absolute Path Name */
    if(*argv[0] == '/') {

    }

    /* Look In Path Directories */
    for(i = 0; dir[i] != NULL; i++) {
        strncat(path_name, dir[i], sizeof(path_name));
        strncat(path_name, "/", sizeof(path_name));
        strncat(path_name, argv[0], sizeof(path_name));
        result = path_name;
        if(access(result, F_OK) == 0) {
            printf("result: %s\n", result);
            return result;
        }
        path_name[0] = '\0';
    }

    /* File Name Not Found In Any Path Variable */
    return NULL;
}
```

Your help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You are not using `strncat` correctly. The last argument should be the maximum number of characters *to append*, not the maximum number of characters that the string should be. Consider using `snprintf` with a  `"%s/%s"` format, etc.

Comment: You really should learn how to use the `gdb` debugger.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
result = path_name;
```

should be:

```
strcpy(result, path_name);
```

Or better, get rid of `path_name` and use `result` directly.

Note that you should remember to free `result` when it's not used, when returning it, free it in the function that calls it. Since you return `NULL` in failure, in that case, free it directly, or it's a memory leak.

And you are using `strncat` wrong, read the [manual](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strncat/).

Answer (score 2):

You cannot return a local array (like your `path_name`) from a function. That local array is inside the [call frame](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack), which gets popped on return.

As others replied, you should do

```
strncpy(result, path_name, MAX_PATH_LEN);
```

and *document* the convention that the caller should free the result.

BTW, your code is quite inefficient; you are allocating a rather large chunk of `MAX_PATH_LEN` (often 4096) for a string which often is much smaller.

If using GNU extensions you could simply use [asprintf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/asprintf.3.html) (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12746885/841108)) or at least remove your `malloc` and `return strdup(path_name);` and use [strdup(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strdup.3.html) (which is standard, not requiring any GNU extension).

And learn how to use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/).

Comment: Plus he's leaking `result` (what it was originally assigned to, that is).

Answer (score 2):

You are assigning values `path_name` more than it can actually hold.

```
    strncat(path_name, dir[i], sizeof(path_name));
    strncat(path_name, "/", sizeof(path_name));
    strncat(path_name, argv[0], sizeof(path_name));
```

should be:

```
    sprintf(path_name, "%s%s%s", dir[i],"/",argv[0]);
```

Comment: Not `%S` but `%s` and without spaces in the format control string.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: Thank you sir, for bringing it to notice

Comment: If you know the size of the buffer, and if the function is available, you should use `snprintf` instead, this makes it more difficult to overrun the buffer.

Comment: Thank you! I ended up using this.

Comment: @JakeZ: Good for you. And, its not about what you use. It is said "In C there is *always* a better way to get it done!". The point is, you gotta learn what to use, where to use and why to do so..

Answer (score 1):

Because of this line:

```
result = path_name;
```

This *reassigns* `result` to point to the local variable `path_name`, which goes out of scope when the function returns. This also means you have a memory leak.

Instead of using the temporary `path_name` variable, write directly into `result`.