# Do I have to free dynamic allocated array after returning it from a function to another?

Tags: c, arrays

Consider the following function:

```
char* color(const char* clr, char* str)
{
    char *output = malloc(strlen(str)+1);

    /* Colorize string. */
    sprintf(output, "%s%s%s", clr, str, CLR_RESET);

    return output;
}
```

The above function  allow us to print colorized messages in linux terminal.

So I can write

```
printf("%s", color(CLR_RED, "This is our own colorized string"));
```

and see the message `This is our own colorized string` in red.

My concern is the `output` string allocated in `color()`. By the time the function returns an allocated element (array in our example) we somewhat need to deallocate it (C does not have a garbage collector).

My question is, what happens to the `output` after is passed to `printf()`? When we exit the function `printf()` the array is still allocated? If it is, how we can deallocate it? Is there any way to write a function that do this for us?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The rule is simple: For each value returned by `malloc(...)/calloc(...)/realloc(NULL, ...) /strdup(...)` there needs to be exactly one call to `free()` passing this very value.

Comment: @alk thank you. I just wanted to be sure.

Comment: You can also printf("%s", CLR_RED "This is..." CLR_RESET);. The strings get concatenated.

Comment: @linuxfan nice.

Comment: This only works if `CLR_RED` is (some macro expanded to) a literal string

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch true. CLR_RED, written all caps, and used as argument to %s, seems that. But good to point it out.

Comment: I often have `#define CLR_RED (stdout_is_tty?"\033[31;1m":"")` where `stdout_is_tty` is a global boolean which was initialized early in `main` with `stdout_is_tty = isatty(STDOUT_FILENO);`

Answer (score 9):

First, your code is wrong. You call `malloc` with a too small size so will have a [buffer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow). And you forgot to test against failure of `malloc`. You probably should code:

```
char *output = malloc(strlen(clr)+strlen(str)+strlen(CLR_RESET)+1);
if (!output) { perror ("malloc in color"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }
sprintf(output, "%s%s%s", clr, str, CLR_RESET);
```

BTW, some systems have [asprintf](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/asprintf.3.html) (which would be easier to [use](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12746885/841108)). IMHO using `sprintf` is dangerous (you should prefer [snprintf](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/snprintf.3.html)).

Then, C programming requires a lot of **conventions**. You should have yours (inspired by usual practice). I recommend to study existing [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) source code (e.g. from [github](http://github.com/)) for inspiration.

You can have a function returning a `malloc`-ed pointer, but your need to *document* that convention (at the very least, as a comment in the common header file *declaring* `color`) and explicit the obligation to call `free` on its result, and follow it elsewhere.

Then, in the function *calling* `color` you would call `free` on the result of `color`.

In general, you should `free` a pointer value *after* `malloc` has been called to obtain it (but of course, take care of [pointer aliases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_aliasing)), but only once that pointer (more precisely the memory zone it points to) is useless.

Don't forget to enable all warnings & debug info when compiling (so `gcc -Wall -g` if using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)). Use the debugger (`gdb`). Use [memory leak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak) detectors like [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/).

You should read a lot more about [C dynamic memory allocation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation) & [virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space).

If on Linux, read also [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/). And reading about [Operating Systems](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/) and about [Garbage Collection](http://gchandbook.org/) will be helpful (at least for relevant concepts).

Comment: `You call malloc with a too small size` what do you mean by that?

Comment: @GeorgeGkas you allocate say 3 bytes and write 15. I'd advise you to read more on basics of C before proceeding, judging from your comments.

Comment: @GeorgeGkas your color codes are probably 5 bytes long each and you need two sequences for around 10 bytes. Your output will be that many bytes longer than you've allocated, every time. Behavior is undefined once you write out of bounds in your sprintf call.

Comment: @GeorgeGkas You need to allocate `strlen(clr) + strlen(str) + strlen(CLR_RESET) + 1` bytes to hold the resulting string.

Answer (score 3):

> My question is, what happens to the output after is passed to
>   printf()? When we exit the function printf() the array is still
>   allocated? If it is, how we can deallocate it? Is there any way to
>   write a function that do this for us?

Yes, after `color` function ends, the memory you allocated for `output` is still there. You need to store the return value of `color` function, and call `free` when you are done using it.

Yes, and as noted in another answer, the size you pass to malloc is small in this case.

---

You can avoid using malloc altogether though.
Declare a string in the caller code, e.g.

```
char someStr[100];
```

and pass to your color function

```
void color(char* output, const char* clr, char* str)
{
    /* Colorize string. */
    sprintf(output, "%s%s%s", clr, str, CLR_RESET);
}
```

Here, no need for malloc anymore.

Call: `color(someStr, CLR_RED, "This is our own colorized string")`

Comment: Do you have any idea where to store it? In what structure? A link list that contains the pointers?

Comment: @GeorgeGkas no just assign it to char *

Comment: In the later case, it would be much better to *explicitly* pass `sizeof(someStr)` to `color` and use `snprintf`

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch yeah, safer, anyway I assumed caller will take care of that by creating someStr of sufficient size :) just showed OP this is also one way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use a global buffer char[whatever]: no need to alloc(), no need to free(). The color() functions always returns that buffer. The only problem, which could be a non-problem, is that color() will be *NOT* reentrant and must be called just once per statement.

```
char g_color_buf[200];

char* color(const char* clr, char* str) {
    sprintf(g_color_buf, "%s%s%s", clr, str, CLR_RESET);
    return g_golor_buf;
}
```

**UPDATE**: from a comment below, it is even better to declare g_color_buf[] as `static` inside the function itself, instead of polluting the global namespace. Doing so does not cure the other problems, but is better anyway.

As said above, this routine should not be used in statements like:

```
printf("%s %s", color(CL_WHITE, "Result:"), color(CL_RED, "Error"));
```

because the second call to color() would destroy the work done by the first call.

Finally, to reply to your question (needed, because otherwise someone can say "you didn't reply"), the memory allocated by color() in your example code will stay there until *you* (no one else) will free it. Considering the mean, normal use you presumably want, it would be uncomfortable to write many times:

```
tmp = color(CL_RED, "hello");
printf("%s", tmp);
free(tmp);
```

The solution to use a global buffer to pass along to color(), and perhaps accompanied by its size, like:

```
printf("%s", color(buffer1, CL_RED, "Hello"));
--or--
printf("%s", color(buffer2, sizeof(buffer2), CL_RED, "HelloHello"));
```

is certainly the most correct, but boring. Well, it is not boring if you like to type!

Comment: That was included in the latest edition of [Georgi's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42471214/841108) before you wrote yours.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch. No. Read well. I'm talking about a global buffer which is not passed to the function as argument. Quite different, simpler to invoke, and _not reentrant_, differently from Giorgi's answer.

Comment: Why a global? why not a `static` function-local? Also, the problem  with reentrancy is not that "you must call it just once per statement": it's that there cannot be any situation where more than one site might call it in a potentially interleaved manner, otherwise UB occurs. It is also not that "the second call to color() would destroy the work done by the first call"; why would that be a problem? The real problem is that the sequencing of the two calls is undefined (as they're function arguments), & so they need not occur sequentially (non-interleaved) at all, never mind in the order written

Comment: @underscore_d: I updated the answer about static local. Good point. About the double call of color() in printf(): it is a problem because, in the end, printf receives two pointers pointing to the same buffer. Clearly, this buffer can not hold _two different contents_ at the same time, so printf() will print two times the same string, which is not the desired result.

Comment: @EJP. You are right. But neither printf() is guaranteed to be thread safe. The OP talks about C, not Posix, and his example is seems printf()-centric. I can imagine that this color() function could be used in different contexts than printing to the console, though.

Comment: @linuxfan Right, I was wrongly envisioning how the call would occur, somehow imagining that `printf` would evaluate each argument separately (though not in a specific order) during execution, which in retrospect is clearly wrong; all arguments must be evaluated before execution of the function's body begins, but the order of that evaluation is unspecified.