# C & Sqlite3 - Variable database & table naming - SQL Syntax error

Tags: c, sqlite, c-preprocessor

I'm trying to write some code that initializes an sql database and table with the name of the database & table set through preprocessor commands and if not set, defaulting to the values given below.

I'm using a macro to stringify whatever name is given. The sqlite3_open correctly opens / creates the database with the given name or the default

```
sqlite3_open(TO_STRING(DB_NAME), &db);
```

For the creation of  the table I'm relying on sprintf.

```
sprintf(str,"CREATE TABLE %s;", TO_STRING(TABLE_NAME));
sql = str;
```

When inspecting my code in debugging, pointer sql seems to be having the correct value of "CREATE TABLE SensorData;". However when I try to execute my code I get the error ***"SQL error: near ";": syntax error"***. Upon inspection it is clear that the error code 110 is returned by the function, I can't seem to find any information on this code however.

I can't seem to figure out what the exact problem is in this case, as the string resulting in the array str seems to be exactly the same as when I create the table in a static way.

This is all my code relevant to the problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sqlite3.h>

#define REAL_TO_STRING(s) #s
#define TO_STRING(s) REAL_TO_STRING(s)   

#ifndef DB_NAME
  #define DB_NAME Sensor.db
#endif

#ifndef TABLE_NAME
  #define TABLE_NAME SensorData
#endif

#define DBCONN sqlite3 

int main()
{

    char *err_msg = 0;
    DBCONN * db;
    int ok = sqlite3_open(TO_STRING(DB_NAME), &db);


    if(ok != SQLITE_OK)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"Cannot open database: %s\n",sqlite3_errmsg(db));
        sqlite3_close(db);
        return 0;
    }

    char * sql;
    char str[100];
    //clear array
    memset(&str[0],0,100);  

    sprintf(str,"CREATE TABLE %s;", TO_STRING(TABLE_NAME));
    sql = str;

    ok = sqlite3_exec(db, sql, 0, 0, &err_msg);

    if (ok != SQLITE_OK ){

      fprintf(stderr, "SQL error: %s\n", err_msg);

      sqlite3_free(err_msg);        
      sqlite3_close(db);

      return 0;
  }

    sqlite3_close(db);

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Your CREATE TABLE query is invalid. Try something like this: CREATE TABLE 'mytable'('id' INTEGER); You need at least one field in the table

Comment: Ah yes, I added several fields and both the table and the database have been created now. This solved the problem, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To turn @Simone Cifani 's comment into a valid answer. The problem was that my CREATE TABLE query was invalid as I did not add any fields to the table. Following solution solved the problem.

Note that I also swapped the sprintf function for the asprintf function, which I highly suggest you read up on if you are planning to do anything similar to this. [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12746885/why-use-asprintf) explains the working of the asprintf function and the difference with the sprintf function very clearly.

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE 

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sqlite3.h>

#define REAL_TO_STRING(s) #s
#define TO_STRING(s) REAL_TO_STRING(s)   

#ifndef DB_NAME
  #define DB_NAME Sensor.db
#endif

#ifndef TABLE_NAME
  #define TABLE_NAME SensorData
#endif

#define DBCONN sqlite3 

int main()
{

    char *err_msg = 0;
    DBCONN * db;
    int rc = sqlite3_open(TO_STRING(DB_NAME), &db);

    if(rc != SQLITE_OK)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"Cannot open database: %s\n",sqlite3_errmsg(db));
        sqlite3_close(db);
        return 0;
    }

    char * sql;
    int size = 0;

    size  = asprintf(&sql,"CREATE TABLE %s (id INT, value REAL, ts INT);", TO_STRING(TABLE_NAME));

    if(size == -1)
        printf("asprintf failed in main\n");

    rc = sqlite3_exec(db, sql, 0, 0, &err_msg);

    if (rc != SQLITE_OK ){

      fprintf(stderr, "SQL error: %s\n", err_msg);
      sqlite3_free(err_msg);        
      sqlite3_close(db);
      free(sql);
      return 0;
  }

    free(sql);
    sqlite3_close(db);
    return 0;

}
```